# What makes items appear in Nautilus sidebar and how to change it?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, filemanager

I'm on Bionic and the version of my Nautilus Filemanager is 3.26.4. I have quite a lot of different network folders defined in fstab: sshfs, nfs, smb, you name it. Plus a couple of USB drives that are plugged in almost constantly.

As you can imagine some of those are more important than others. So I'd really like to have a say in what Nautilus displays in the sidebar and what doesn't show up. Instead, Nautilus seems to have decided for itself what to display there and presents an interesting collection of items that is less than optimal.

I can't find out why rarely used items are deemed worthy to be displayed in the sidebar while important ones are banned to the vaults of "other places". And how I can change this.

Do you have any ideas or workarounds for this? Where do you control the behaviour of Nautilus' sidebar beyond a couple of bookmarks?

Comment: Try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB 19.10 and see if favorites now shows what you're looking for. This behavior became the default in 19.10.

Comment: Hm. So I'll have to wait for "Focal", and hope the best.

Answer (score 2):

Your bookmarks (the locations in the left side bar) are listed in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`.

You can edit that file and restart Nautilus.

Comment: That's useful information, and there are a couple I am pretty sure I didn't put there. But I am more interested in the network drives that get displayed automatically.